# Unexpected escaping in Eclipselink LIKE query

Tags: jpa, escaping, eclipselink, oracle12c

I need help troubleshooting a strange bug. There is an application running on Oracle 12 and Eclipselink 2.5.2 with a simple search screen that uses a LIKE clause and "%" as wildcard.

The application creates the query using criteria builder. A QA tester entered only the "_" underscore character in the search screen. The application code wraps the user-specified text with the '%' character.

```
new StringBuilder("%").append(param).append("%").toString()
```

At runtime, when the query is executed the prepared statement parameters are bound as follows:

```
bind => [%\_%, ACTIVE, IT, 20, 0]
```

meaning that unexpectedly (at least for me) Eclipselink has decided to escape the "_" char with a leading "\". The database is Oracle 12. I would then expect the resulting query to be suffixed with "ESCAPE '\'" but this is not happening and the query returns nothing because in absence of the escape clause "\_" is processed as if it was the original user search string.

What am I missing?

Comment: Pretty weird, this does not happen with Oracle 10 e eclipseLink 2.3.2. Have you tried so see wthat the http traffic looks like ?

Comment: Look at the invoked SQL, via Oracle facilities/logging, to see what was actually passed

Comment: Check your code, and print off the 'param' variable and the resulting string built from the StringBuilder, but EclipseLink will not escape anything you pass in, especially when you are using parameter binding, unless you've told it to.  Show the actual query and expression you are building.

Comment: Looks like a cross post from here https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1771681/#msg_1771681 where you show more information, and seem to wrap the 'param' in a method: append(escape(param))

Comment: It is a cross post indeed, I noted that most questions in the forum are unanswered so after a few days I tried here. I removed the  escape(param) here because it just added confusion. escape() uses StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava() from Commons Lang, which does nothing in this case, if you pass in input a "\_" it returns the same "\_".

Comment: Show the exact string you are passing in, and the code used to build the query as EclipseLink will do nothing with the string you pass it other than pass it through so I suspect your code between the input value and creating the query is modifying it.

Comment: @Chris is right, the problem is in the code. Not in the Java code, but in a remote JS application that posts a wrong query string to the server. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipselink does not perform any escaping, this was a defect in a remote client code. Sorry for the noise.